# Order ggplot bar graph by descending n with MRE (not yet answered elsewhere)

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a problem with ordering my bar graph by descending n. The graph is supposed to display the most frequent words in a corpus of TXT files. I've been told that the same question has been answered elsewhere, but none of the code snippets suggested there produce the desired result.

```
# create minimal dataset:
# create two TXT files
# content of first TXT file: aaa bbb ccc
# content of second TXT file: aaa bbb bbb
# save both files to a folder called TXTs in current working directory

# load packages
library("tidyr")
library("dplyr")
library("purrr")
library("readr")
library("tidytext")
library("ggplot2")

# function to read all files from folder into dataframe
read_folder <- function(infolder) {
  tibble(file = dir(infolder, full.names = TRUE)) %>%
    mutate(text = map(file, read_lines)) %>%
    transmute(id = basename(file), text) %>%
    unnest(text)
}

# create corpus from folder with TXT files
raw_text <- read_folder("TXTs")
tidy_text <- raw_text %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text)

# count most frequent words
# and display in descending order
# ATTEMPT #1
tidy_text %>%
  dplyr::count(word, sort = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(word = reorder(word, n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = word, y = n)) +
  geom_col() +
  xlab(NULL) +
  coord_flip()

# count most frequent words
# and display in descending order
# ATTEMPT #2
tidy_text %>%
  dplyr::count(word, sort = TRUE) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(factor(word), n), y = n)) +
  geom_col() +
  xlab(NULL) +
  coord_flip()
```

Neither of these two attempts provide the decided output. The order in the graph should be bbb-aaa-ccc, but it is bbb-ccc-aaa. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: The problem is your `tidy_text` tibble is still grouped. I'm actually not sure why you are grouping at all really. I think `tidy_text <- raw_text %>% unnest_tokens(word, text)` would work just fine. The `group_by` messes with the `mutate()` so the `reorder` can't see all the values.

Comment: Thank you so much! What an elegant fix! I was comparing novels before, so I think that's why I had used group_by.

Comment: Just make sure you turn the grouping off when comparing across all values. You can also use the `ungroup()` function if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `forcats::fct_reorder` as described in section 15.4 of Headley's book [here](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html).  Illustration on `gss_cat` sample data included in `tidyverse` -

```r
library(tidyverse)
#unorganised
gss_cat %>%
  group_by(relig) %>%
  summarise(
    age = mean(age, na.rm = TRUE),
    tvhours = mean(tvhours, na.rm = TRUE),
    n = n()
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(tvhours, relig)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

```r
#ordered
gss_cat %>%
  group_by(relig) %>%
  summarise(
    age = mean(age, na.rm = TRUE),
    tvhours = mean(tvhours, na.rm = TRUE),
    n = n()
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(tvhours, fct_reorder(relig, tvhours))) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>